# how to remove validation on input select that used by two different actions

Tags: validation, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have an input select field named risk_level_id for my advance_search action in Controller Abc.

`echo $this->Form->input('risk_level_id',array('empty'=>'Choose One'));`

there is another action in Controller Abc named add_issue, in that action there also a select field for selecting the risk_level_id from drop down that is required field in that form.

validation process is defined for risk_level_id in Model.

for advance_search action i didn't want the risk_level_id field is to be required.
so what will i have to do to make it required field in one action and in other action it didn't seems to be required with in a same controller and Model.

Comment: Waht is exact version of cake you are using?

Comment: I doubt that, really.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just to add this line in your action

```
 $this->ModelName->validator()->remove('Action');
```

if u you want to remove only one rule on any field.

```
 $this->ModelName->validator()->remove('Action Name', 'Rule Name');
```